# Lim sup of sequence of sets and theirs unions

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I have to prove the following equality:

$$\left(\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n\right)\cup\left(\limsup_{n \to \infty} B_n\right) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(A_n\cup B_n\right)$$

Can somebody help me to prove this?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 4):

If $(C_n,n\geqslant 1)$ is a collection of sets, then $x\in\limsup_n C_n$ means that $I(x):=\{n\geqslant 1,x\in C_n\}$ is infinite.

Since $A_n\subset A_n\cup B_n$ for each $n$, we certainly have $\limsup_nA_n\subset\limsup_n (A_n\cup B_n)$.

For the reverse inclusion, let $x\in \limsup_n (A_n\cup B_n)$. Then $x\in A_n\cup B_n$ for infinitely many $n$. Defining $I:=\{n\geqslant 1,x\in A_n\}$ and $J:=\{n\geqslant 1,x\in B_n\}$, we have that $I\cup J$ is infinite, hence $I$ or $J$ is infinite.

Comment: Thanks for this! Is it also true that $\left(\limsup_n A_n\right)\cap\left(\limsup_n B_n\right) = \limsup_n A_n \cap B_n$?

Answer (score 1):

I just answered the question [Understanding the supremum limit of a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503816/understanding-the-supremum-limit-of-a-set/503947#503947) which has at least some to do with this. It is proven there that $x$ belongs to $\limsup_n A_n$ is equivalent to that $x$ belongs to infinitely many $A_n$'s.

Using this description and defining $C_n=A_n\cup B_n$ one easily checks that if $x$ belongs to
$$
\left(\limsup_n A_n\right)\cup\left(\limsup_n B_n\right)
$$
then $x$ belongs to either infinitely many $A_n$ or infinitely many $B_n$ and thus to infinitely many $C_n$. This gives the inclusion ''$\subseteq$''.

For the other inclusion consider some $x$ in $\limsup_n C_n$ so that $x$ belongs to infinitely many $C_n$. Then assume for contradiction that $x$ only belongs to finitely many $A_n,B_n$. Then there exist a $k$ so that $x$ does not belong to $A_n$ nor $B_n$ for $n>k$. But this implies that $x$ does not belong to $C_n$ for $n>k$ either which is a contradiction. The inclusion ''$\supseteq$'' follows.