# spectrum of some operators

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, spectral-radius

Suppose $A$ is an positive invertible operator in $B(H)$,$\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of positive invertible operators which converges to $A$ in norm topology. Can we conclude that $\log(\sigma(A_nA^{-1})) \to \{0\}$?

Comment: How are you defining convergence of sets here?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476159/limits-of-sequences-of-sets?r=SearchResults

Comment: For that definition of set convergence, the answer is surely "no". For example, under that defintion $\{1/n\} \to \emptyset$, not $\{0\}$. However, before I go any further, let me confirm that by $H$ you mean a Hilbert space, by $\sigma(A)$ you mean the spectrum of $A$, and by $\log(S)$ for a set $S$, you mean the set $\{\log s\mid s \in S\}$.

Comment: Yes,$H$ is a Hilbert space,$\sigma(A)$ is the spectrum of $A$.

Comment: Okay. Then $A_n = (1+1/n)I$ is a counter-example, as $\sigma(A_nA^{-1}) = \{1 + 1/n\}$ and the limit is empty (by that definition, $p \in \lim_n S_n$ if and only if $p$ is an element of all but a finite number of the $S_n$). However, there are other ways of defining set convergence. I think the definition that best suits here would be $$\lim_n S_n = \{s \mid \exists (s_n), s_n \to s \text{ and } \forall n, s_n \in S_n\}$$If $H$ is finite-dimensional, the result is true using this definition. I've not yet thought through the infinite-dimensional case, though.

Comment: I saw the conclusion in a document.It states as following :the conditions are the same as above,then we have $diam \log(\sigma(A_nA^{-1})) \to \{0\}$,where $diam()$ represents a diameter of a set.It mentions that we can conclude the fact by using the upper seimicontinuousity of the spectrum.

Comment: Since the diameter of a set is a real number, not a set itself, that should be $\operatorname{diam} \log(\sigma(A_nA^{-1})) \to 0$, not $\{0\}$. And there is no longer any concern about what definition of convergence of sets is being used.

Answer (score 0):

The "log" has no effect for the question you've asked. I can only assume your source included it because of some other purpose. Since the logarithm is continuous, $\operatorname{diam} \log(\sigma(A_nA^{-1})) \to 0$ if and only if $\operatorname{diam} \sigma(A_nA^{-1}) \to 0$.

Since $A_n \to A$, we have $A_nA^{-1} \to I$. By upper semi-continuity of the spectral diameter, $$\limsup_n \operatorname{diam} \sigma(A_nA^{-1}) \le \operatorname{diam} \sigma(I) = \operatorname{diam}
\, \{1\} = 0$$
But since the diameter is $\ge 0$ by definition, it follows that $\operatorname{diam} \sigma(A_nA^{-1}) \to 0$.

Comment: I only know the fact that spectrum is upper semicontinuous,how to conclude the upper semicontiunuousity of spectral diameter ?